# Python: Keep track of quotes when loading JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string

I'm building a small script where i use a JSON file, do some processing with it and save some outputs into a text file. This is an example of JSON i can use:

```json
{
   "hidden_layer_sizes" : [100,200],
   "activation": ["logistic", "tanh"]
}
```

I am currently loading my JSON with this python function:

```py
import json
def load_json(json_file):
   with open(json_file) as f:
      data = json.load(f)
   return data
```

This function returns the standard python dictionary. I don't think there's any problem related to it and works fine. The problem is that i need - somehow - a way to keep double quotes of values declared inside it (i.e. `"logistic"`) and save them in my output file. The following is an example of output file generated from the JSON above:

desired:

```
hidden_layer_sizes=100;activation="logistic";
hidden_layer_sizes=100;activation="tanh";
hidden_layer_sizes=200;activation="logistic";
hidden_layer_sizes=200;activation="tanh";
```

What i have now:

```
hidden_layer_sizes=100;activation=logistic;
hidden_layer_sizes=100;activation=tanh;
hidden_layer_sizes=200;activation=logistic;
hidden_layer_sizes=200;activation=tanh;
```

I was thinking of trying to keep track of values that have string type and surround them with quotes before saving into the file, but i would like to know if there's any other elegant way of achieving this result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code that writes the file

Comment: Are doing any processing on `data` before writing into the file?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM no, i am not. If there's a way to filter values in a dict where a condition is matched (type == str), then my problem can be solved.

Comment: don't check for string types. just use the built in `repr` function to get the string value, it will wrap quotes around it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the string encoded, you need to re-encode it rather than trying to work around this with the parser. Call `json.dumps(activation_function)` and you'll get a quoted string.

```
In [9]: print(json.dumps("foo"))
"foo"
```